# GCC ARM optimization causing fault

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I've been developing a project using the GCC ARM C compiler with no optimization for over a year (about 327K code size).

Performance concern has recently caused me to use optimization level og so I still have good debugging information.

Code size using optimization level og dropped to 217K -- with little code size changing from that when using optimization o2 -- so I'm staying with og.

I'm randomly getting what I refer to as a fault which I don't understand and am asking if someone may explain possible causes to me.

I'm using a j-link with the crossworks IDE and the cpu is a Cortex M4.

Depending on a compilation version, the cpu will get to an instruction (machine code) where it is branching back to itself - thereby locking up.  The debugger is of no help and the call stack does not appear to be correct.

It is not the hardfault vector.

If I add a "nop" or two, I can get the problem to move or to not occur at all which leads me to believe it may be a data alignment issue.

Does optimization level og impose data or code alignment concerns and if so, what steps might I take to comply with them?

I have const char strings in the code.  Will the compiler automatically place them with proper alignment?

Any thoughts or comments?

Thanks

Comment: I noted the buggy stack in Crossworks too, please complain to crossworks.

Comment: Most errors I get when going from going from O0 to O2 are my own errors due to undefined behaviour. This is difficult to find and usually involve some binary search on the code to find the minimal (not) working code.

Comment: Surt - can you explain what you mean by doing a binary search - for what?  As for crossworks, unless you have active support they totally ignore you.  I've found and documented issues with their IDE and get no response.  Things got bad over a year ago when Seeger bought them.

Comment: Removing more and more of the code until the problem disappear, ideally half each time. Then continue on the part of the code where the problem showed up.

Comment: If I remember it on Monday I'll ask my colleague what he did to make it work.

Comment: have you tried GCC `-fsanitize=undefined`?

Comment: I resolved it.  I instrumented my version of malloc and free to catch a buffer over-write and that's exactly what I did.  I had originally acquired a buffer for a message of a specific size and later made the message more robust but forgot to increase the buffer.  I overwrote the buffer leaving data in freertos's memory link list.  It just so happened, the data ended up being a pointer to cpu registers so when freertos did it next malloc -
 it attempted to read from cpu register space and faulted.  My dumb error.